# How to create a API user in Marketing Cloud Org

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

I want to connect my Marketing cloud org and Salesforce org using the marketing cloud managed package. In the documentation for installing the app it is mentioned that I need to create a API user in the marketing cloud Org but I'm not able to create a user as the create button on users is non-clickable.
Also, the currently active users are also not showing the any checkbox of API user.
How can I create this API user and why is it not giving me the permission to create new users?

Answer (score 1):

Check your user roles/ permission. You need to be a Marketing Cloud Admin to create/ edit user details.

Comment: how can I check my user roles/permission in marketing cloud?

Comment: Admin > My Users > UserName. Then check the username box then select Manage Roles. The API Access is on the User screen. Click the name link on the My Users screen. The field is API User Yes/No.